# Unity animations - yield return new WaitForSeconds(secs) not working

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, wait

Why doesn't the animation play in Unity when I use this code? How could I make the program wait for the animation to end? In JavaScript (or UnityScript) this approach has worked.

```
public bool Attacking { get; set; }
private Animator anim;

void Start() 
{
    anim = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
}

private IEnumerator Attack()
{
    Attacking = true;

    anim.SetTrigger("Attack"); // this is not playing

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(attackLength);

    Attacking = false;
}
```

Comment: where are you running coroutine?

Comment: You need to call/start the `Attack()` coroutine function. `StartCoroutine(Attack());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you run a Coroutine:

```
StartCoroutine(Attack());
```

or

```
StartCoroutine("Attack");
```

If you try to run it like a usual function it wont work.

So here is solution:

```
public void PlayAttack() 
{
    StartCoroutine(Attack());
}
```

[Learn More](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html)